# How to not waste space due to large integration limits?

Tags: spacing, equations, width, integral

I have the following formula:

[image]

As can be seen, it is too wide for the column and I'd like to have it fit the column.
Latex wastes a lot of space by not putting the integrand between the integration limits (see arrow).

I tried using `\limits` but this does not improve the situation: Latex still does not put the limits above/under the integrand and continues to waste space (and the formula stays too wide).

My code is:

```
\begin{align}
    z[m] &= \frac{1}{R} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} y[n] \, e^{-j \frac{2\pi}{R} k_m n} \int_{(m-1)R-n}^{m R-n} \varphi(\tau) \, e^{-j \frac{2\pi}{R} k_m\tau} \, \operatorname{d}\tau,
\end{align}
```

I am using amsmath and the IEEEtran document class in two-column mode.

Is there a way to tell Latex to print the limits above/below the integrand?

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ and whether your document is typeset in one-column or two-column mode. Please also show the code for equation 37, so that we don't have to enter it by hand while searching for a solution.

Comment: Thanks -- done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please always provide anm MWE, which reproduce your problem. Retype your equation and knowing nothing about your document layout make hard time to us in helping you. Help us to help you ...

`\mathllap` from `mathtools` is your friend:

**Edit**
with considering equation which you provide in edited question, the solution can be:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
    z[m] = \frac{1}{R} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} y[n] \, e^{-j \frac{2\pi}{R} k_m n} 
            \mathrlap{\int_{(m-1)R-n}^{m R-n}}\quad  % <--- 
            \varphi(\tau) \, \operatorname{e}^{-j \frac{2\pi}{R} k_m\tau} \, \operatorname{d}\tau,
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2-9]
\end{document}
```

[image]

or you can write equation in two lines, for example use `split` or `multline` math environment defined in `amsmath` as well in `mathtools`.